# Bootstrap alert close time can not be set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide alert with the following script example, but none of them workes and I can't set time whenever the alert to close after it's displayed. I'm stuck at this. Please, tell me, where my mistake is.

Example 1:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { 
     $(".alert-notification").alert('close'); 
}, 8000);
```

Example 2:

```
$(".alert-notification").delay(8000).slideUp(200, function(){
    $(".alert-notification").alert('close');
});
```

Both example are working and closing the alert but not in the specific time. I call this functions in `jQuery document.ready` Thanks!

Comment: When are you calling this?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: I call them in document.ready event. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually call them when you are displaying the alert, not during the `$(document).ready()` function.

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".alert").hide().removeClass("hidden");
  $("#callAlert").click(function () {
    $(".alert").slideDown(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $(".alert").slideUp();
      }, 5000);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
.alert {background: red; color: white;}
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert hidden">This is an alert!</div>
<button id="callAlert">Hi</button>
```

Comment: Can I attach this snipper to another event, because I display the alert after a form submition, which returns the html on success or failure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still attach it to document.ready indeed and works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple slide up transition using the script you sent

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.alert-notification').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".alert-notification").slideUp();
    }, 100);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-notification">test</div>
```